# Why does division(?) yield this number?

Tags: c++, floating-point, division, divide-by-zero

Rephrasing question :

The following code (Not C++ - written in an in-house scripting language)

```
if(A*B != 0.0)
{
   D = (C/(A*B))*100.0;
}
else
{
   D = 0.0;
}
```

yields a value of

`90989373681853939930449659398190196007605312719045829137102976436641398782862768335320454041881784565022989668056715169480294533394160442876108458546952155914634268552157701346144299391656459840294022732906509880379702822420494744472135997630178480287638496793549447363202959411986592330337536848282003701760.000000`

for D. We are 100% sure that `A != 0.0`. And we are almost 100% sure that `B == 0.0`. We never use such infinitesimally small values (close to 0.0 but not 0.0) such as the value of `B` that this value of `C` suggests. It is impossible that it acquired that value from our data. Can `A*B` yield anything that is not equal to 0.0 when `B` is 0?

Comment: so if this isn't C++, why does it have a C++ tag? (and of course, how do you expect people to be able to explain to you how your own in-house scripting language works? ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you divided by was **not** in fact 0, just very, very close.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using IEEE floating point numbers it is not a good idea to use equal or not equal in this case with floating point numbers. Even if the same value like -0.0 and +0.0 they are not equal from a bitwise perspective which is what the equate does.  Even if using other float formats, equal and not equal are discouraged.

Instead put some sort of range on it e=a*b;  if ((e<0.0002)||(e>0.0002) then...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are accruing error from previous calculations, so you divison is by a really small decimal, but not zero. You should add a margin of error if you want to catch something like this, psuedocode: `if(num < margin_of_error) ret inf;`, or use the epsilon method to be even safer